# Windows ASLR and address rewriting

Tags: windows, aslr

I am just starting out learning about how code injection works and various defences.
I understand how and what ASLR does, but am struggling a little while looking at it in action.

By hijacking execution, I have added functionality (messagebox on startup) to mspaint.exe, calc.exe, and winword.exe.  On WinXP these execute as desired.  On Windows 7, the first two execute as desired but winword.exe runs into what I assume is ASLR:

[1] A call or jmp to an address in another executable section gets adjusted and executed properly.

[2] Similar instructions in that new section (call or jmp) are also adjusted properly

[3] Instructions to DLL APIs such as 'call LoadLibraryW', or simple memory access such as 'mov dword [esp], 40402d' do not get adjusted and so point to invalid address space.

Number [3] seems to happen even when I add these instructions directly to the .text section, right alongside an existing identical instruction that gets adjusted properly.

For example:

Using winword.exe, the instruction at 300010f0 is 'call [30001004]' (call GetProcAddress).
Running under ollydbg this shows it has been adjusted to 'call [04106b2f]'.
However, if I change the entrypoint instruction (300010cc) to be 'call [30001004]', this does not get adjusted at all.

Can someone explain or point me to some enlightenment as to the rules governing when and where instructions are adjusted like this? (or if I am being a complete numpty, a pointer towards some useful further reading would be appreciated)

Many thanks.

Comment: The loader cannot adjust addresses blindly scanning the executable, the addresses to fix are written in the relocation section. If you add hard-coded references about addresses in the executable without the corresponding entry in the relocations it's normal that it doesn't get adjusted.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that ASLR is not meant as a defense against local code injection (if you can inject a dll inside an executable you already have more than enough privileges to snoop around and see where stuff got relocated), but as a mitigation technique against unauthorized code execution exploits (such as buffer overruns/"return to libc"-style attacks).

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense.  Thanks man, I really appreciate the answer.  Like I said, I'm just starting and trying to wade through all this.